# SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser returns wrong user (Broken user database?)

Tags: document-library, permissions, user-accounts, spcontext

This code snippet is used to Break Role Inheritance on a Document Library and set the current user as the only user who has "Read" priviliges on that Library:

```
            SPUser oUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://<<server>>/websites/gwp/"))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        SPList list = web.Lists["test_GWP"];
                        if (!list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
                        {
                            list.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
                        }
                        SPRoleDefinition roleDef = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
                        SPRoleAssignment spRoleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(oUser);
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        spRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDef);
                        list.RoleAssignments.Add(spRoleAssignment);
                        list.Update();
                        web.Update();
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

After running this code, the Document Library gets assigned to a completely different user (not pool account)!

Tested on different users, browsers and workstations.

Do you know why SharePoint behaves as described?

FYI: A while ago i added a bunch of users to the website, namingly an AD-Group which itself contained an AD-Group. Did this break my SharePoint user database by any chance?

Comment: From where this code is getting executed?

Comment: This code gets executed on an application page which i call as a modal dialog on a newform.aspx using javascript.

The call of the modal dialog:

SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);

Comment: Tried debuging code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that `SPRoleAssignment` is using the ID of the passed in `oUser`, but the user with that ID in `http://<<server>>/websites/gwp/` is very unlikely to be the same user as the one with that ID in `SPContext.Current.Web` unless `SPContext.Current.Web` is `http://<<server>>/websites/gwp/`.

So you need to change

```
SPRoleAssignment spRoleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(oUser);
```

to

```
SPUser oUser2 = web.EnsureUser(oUser.LoginName);
SPRoleAssignment spRoleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(oUser2);
```